# Values of virtual characters

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $K$ be a number field and $K^c\subset\mathbb{C}$ its algebraic (separable) closure. Denote by $R_G$ the additive group of functions generated by the characters of n-dimensional representations of $G$ over $K^c$.

Could anyone explain the following comment made in Frohlich's book 'galois module theory of algebraic integers'--

The values of the characters of $G$, i.e. the numbers $\chi(g)$ $(\chi\in R_G, g\in G)$ lie in some number field $E$ containing $K$, which is *Galois* over $\mathbb{Q}$.

First of all, can $E$ be formed by adjoining the finitely many values $\chi(g)$ where $\chi$ runs over the irreducible characters in $R_G$ and $g$ runs over $G$?

Comment: In some sense yes: $\chi(g)$ is a sum of roots of unity, so $K[\chi] = K[\chi(g):g \in G]$ is a Galois extension of $K$ with abelian Galois group, so super nice. However, technically no. Let $K$ be not-galois and let $G=1$. Obvious $K[\chi]=K$ is not Galois. If $K$ itself is Galois, then yes, everything is fine.

Comment: So is the claim made in Frohlich incorrect in the sense that K must also be Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$? Also I don't quite see how $K[\chi]$ is a normal extension of $K$. Thanks